# c# selenium | how to get values ​in table same column

Tags: c#, selenium

I wrote a code to list the names of the wordpress categories. But I was not successful. The category names column is marked in red.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnLk1.jpg

this is the code I wrote:

```
var table = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("tbody"));
var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
foreach (var row in rows)
{
    IList<IWebElement> satirlar = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
    foreach (var satir in satirlar)
    {
        var a = satir.Text;
        listBox1.Items.Add(a);

    }
}
```

output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzWgb.jpg

I just want to list the category names. but the number of articles in the category and the short name of the category are listed. I don't want this to happen. Only category names should be listed. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a=satir.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.row-title")).Text;
```

Comment: When I tried with the code you provided, only one category name was listed and finally it gave an error. I want to list all the category names that exist.   
         https://i.imgur.com/L1DHliY.jpg

Comment: Can you share your DOM so that i could see the structure ?

Comment: You can see the category names on the category page in any wordpress site. see all the doms there  for ex: https://demo.com/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=category

Comment: The link you provided is not working. Getting `The event you were trying to access is not available.`

Comment: okay, so the problem here is that there are four TDs inside a row and you want to grab the first one's value. Try this: IList<IWebElement> satirlar = row.FindElements(By.Xpath("//td[@data-colname='Name']/strong/a")); foreach (var satir in satirlar) { var a = satir.Text; listBox1.Items.Add(a); }

Comment: thanks for the code. however, the listing process was repeated 3 times and the category names were printed 3 times. Can it be printed once? and it didn't work when I tried this on different wordpress site. Although the category pages are the same on all wordpress sites ..   https://imgur.com/PojEsdy

Comment: This is probably happening because there are 3 values in the array you're looping. Please debug your code to see what's in `satirlar`. Can't say why it's failing on other sites. Better to check if the same selectors apply to those pages as well. Please upvote my answer, as it's helping with the issue.

Comment: The listing process is repeating because you are looping rows as well. First foreach loop is not required in this case.Try this: 'var table = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("tbody")); IList<IWebElement> satirlar = table.FindElements(By.Xpath("//td[@data-colname='Name']/strong/a")); foreach (var satir in satirlar) { var a = satir.Text; listBox1.Items.Add(a); }'

Comment: really thank you so much. I solved my problem thanks to you. The reason why it doesn't work on every site is because the data-colname is different.    This code snippet lists the category names in all wordpress sites. I am thankful to you. :)             //td[@class='name column-name has-row-actions column-primary']/strong/a"));

Comment: I am glad that it helped you.